# uitabbarcontroller storyboard: connecting viewcontroller that's already connected to another uitabbarctrl

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard

I'm trying to reuse some of my view in my storyboard.
I start with a uitabbarcontroller and have some views connected for each tab.
Now i dropped a NEW uitabbarcontroller into the storyboard and I want to connect one of it's tabs to the SAME viewcontroller that is connected to the original tabbar.

Can you 'reuse' viewcontrollers in the storyboard like that? Or do you have to create new viewcontrollers?
I assume the former works, as I'm able to do it else where in the storyboard by choosing 'push'.
It's just not working with the uitabbar if I choose 'relationship'.

ok. I found the cause of my crash and I think I know what's going on. It appears that if I connect another uitabbarcontroller, then indices for the views on the first tabbar get screwed up. What I'm doing to getting references to the viewcontrollers in the uitabbar using

```
UINavigationController* ar_nav=[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
_artvc = [ar_nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
if (![_artvc isKindOfClass:[ArtistTableViewController class]])
{
    TGLog(@"ERR wrong class! %@", [_artvc class]);
    exit(0);
}
```

As soon as I connect the second uitabbar Turns out that index 1 isn't that class (even though the storyboard shows that it is).

using this code on my original tabbar controller

```
UINavigationController* n;
for (n in self.viewControllers)
{
    UIViewController* vc=[n.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    TGLog(@"%@", [vc class]);
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[ArtistTableViewController class]])
    {
        _artvc = (ArtistTableViewController*)vc;
    }
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[SongsTableViewController class]])
    {
        _stvc = (SongsTableViewController*)vc;
    }
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[AlbumTableViewController class]])
    {
        _altvc = (AlbumTableViewController*)vc;
    }

}
```

works fine until I connect the second uitabbar. Once I do that, my viewcontroller is gone from the loop.

Comment: i'm going to recreate a better question with a blank project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. it has something to do (possibly) with the fact that I'm doing UITabbar->navcontroller->uitableview

When I add my second tabbar and create it's own navcontroller and connect it. Then 'reuse' the original tableview by connecting from the navcontroller to the tableview. THis doesn't seem to screw up the original tabbar.

here's a screenshot of my storyboard
http://www.thumbgenius.dynalias.com/tabbar_vc_reuse.png

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely possible. Are you sure that the connection being made is to the view?

I apologize; that was unclear. When you are holding control and dragging the blue connection line, make sure you are connecting to the view itself (not anything else).

You should be able to create that relationship between the UITabBarController and the view, even if it is being shared by another UITabBarController.

What does it show you as your options when you try?

Comment: thanks for the help. I'm dragging to a uitableviewcontroller. It gives me 4 options: relationship, push, model, custom. I assume i choose relationship because I want that view controller to be the VC for my tab. it crashes right away - which I assume is when it's loading the storyboard.

Comment: it works fine if I had dropped a new VC on the storyboard and use that. but not one that's already used.

Comment: maybe I should have clarified something. I have uitabbar->navcontroller->uitableview. could it have something to do with the navcontroller being there? (i've tried connecting to both the navcontroller and the tableview.

Comment: Your link to your storyboard picture did not work :( and I'm not sure why your having trouble accessing it through the loop if everything is setup right. I do not believe that you can connect the first navigation controller to the second, I would stick with connecting the second navigation controller to the UITableView. Make sure that you are setting the UITableView as the root view controller for the new navigation controller.