# Two UITabBarControllers sharing one ViewController (as tab content)?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Situation: two UITabBarController's, each with their own tabs, but last tab in *both* is identical so want *one* UIViewController to show content.

**Issue at runtime: Shared item only appears in *one* of the tab sets when shown.**

Question: anyone know a way to make this work?

Link to external graphic of storyboard setup: (sorry, don't have enough reputation to post images here!)
[Storyboard graphic](http://www.7thcodex.com/stackoverflow/storyboard.png)

An Xcode project with that storyboard:
[XCode Project](http://www.7thcodex.com/stackoverflow/tabcontroller_proj.zip)

Each tab content item has it's own UIViewController class. They contain no code except the line to make the back buttons work.

(Yes, I know this is odd. Real situation is an iPad app where tab controllers are shown in popovers; popovers are "property editors" where different objects have different properties, but all share a common set of properties... thus one tab for "unique" props, one shared tab content for the "common" props all objects have.)

I've found a couple ways around this to get the effect I want, but if this storyboard worked it would be a much easier solution.

-- Other info, somewhat unrelated to question --

Alternate solution I'm using: TabBarControllers only link to one VC as tab content. When that tab VC loads, I use code to (a) instantiate shared VC from storyboard by identifier, (b) add that new VC object to the TabBarController via [tabController setViewControllers:list animated:NO].

(Another possible solution I like even less: not using a TabBarController, and presenting content VC's with my own "tab" graphic drawn into them, each showing "myself" as selected. Yuk.)

So I have a working solution, I'm just curious as to why this doesn't work (just a known thing in iOS API, or some magical property setting that might render it functional?)

Comment: Note similar question with a different focus (odd stuff going on there with tables and re-used views and such...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620619/uitabbarcontroller-storyboard-connecting-viewcontroller-thats-already-connecte?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Your solution where you add the second tab in code, can be done in the storyboard by just copying the shared controller, and hooking one instance to each tab bar controller. In either scenario, you're getting two different instance of the "shared" controller.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is not having to edit the UI layout in several copies of the "one" storyboard scene when I decide it needs to have a different background color and button layout. In this example, there would only be two copies. In my actual app, there will likely be 10+, hence the desire to share.  Was trying to avoid externalizing the UI into .XIB files and loading from there, which is what storyboards are intended to move away from.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the same view controller instance into two tab controllers. The problem is that a view (`UIView`) instance can only have one parent view (`superview`). When you try to add the view controller to the 2nd tab, the view controller's view gets removed from its first parent (the first tab) and then added to the 2nd tab.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I'm not certain that's the root of the issue. The entire TabBarController button disappears, not just view. The 2nd ViewController is never set at all in the second TabBarController's ViewControllers array. While it's true that [view addSubview:sub] causes the sub to be removed from any existing parent view as a side effect, the issue seems more complex than that. I'd like to get confirmation that apple's Storyboard implementation is incapable of automatically instantiating two instances of the SharedViewController (creating two view objects).

Comment: Also: only one TabBarController is presented at a time, so why isn't each capable of making full use of the one instance of the SharedViewController? I agree there would be issues having View in two places at once, but that isn't the case here unless API is holding the full ViewController set for the storyboard in memory when not presented. It doesn't seem to matter which TabBarController you show first, so it's not like when you show it it's "getting control" of the View and so second presentation later grabs the view from someone else's hierarchy. Tab is *never* shown in second TBController.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon your thread while running into the same issue today...
The solution is to just make a duplicate of the view controller in story board and attach the duplicate to the other tab bar controller.
I just did it and it works...
I think the 'rdelmar' is right about this... copy it and set it ..!!

Comment: Thereby creating a nightmare of updating a dozen copies of the storyboard scene every time you want to make a layout change. Duplicating things and using identical-but-distinct copies in multiple places just makes the programmer in me want to throw up a little bit...  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same issue today. I managed to come up with a workaround that seems to do the trick. The key is to add a layer of separation between the tabbar and the controller you want to reuse. From each tabbar, I created a relationship to a distinct UIViewController with a container view. Then you can do an 'embed' segue from the container to the controller you actually want to reuse as the tab view. It is not quite as clean as a direct connection (not sure why that is not supported) since you do have to create a controller class for each reuse case. It is still a better solution than the nightmare of having to duplicate the actual tab view ( as well as any additional views that connect to it) for every use.

Hope this helps. Let me know if anyone needs more details.

Comment: I obviously moved on (and went ahead with the duplication) but I think your solution would work... assuming you can have multiple "inbound" ebed segues for a content view controller. You're right that it's less direct, and creates a pain because the tab controller can't refer to it's content (which would be the container view controller) directly. But obviously no one has posted a better solution... :-)